# Updated template (.dwt) and index.html launching without CSS styling

Tags: html, css, templates, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I was handed a site to update at my job that utilizes one template file. I have made changes to both the template file and the index file as well as several CSS files. What happens when I launch the website live is that the sites contents appear without any styling/functionality. I believe I have linked to all the correct styling links in my head sections because in Dreamweaver the sites render perfectly fine in both Firefox and IE. I'm in a jam at my job. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

UPDATE: I selected the option from Dreamweaver's Modify menu: "Apply template to page" which corrected some of the CSS reference issues. The page renders perfectly now in IE 9 but still no styling whatsoever in Firefox. Any ideas from anyone? I'm completely stuck now. Thanks for all the answers so far!

Comment: Can you show us the website to inspect or give us the full render html

Comment: The website is http://www.wtc.army.mil/    If needed I can provide other code as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox developer tools, check the Network tab for any 404s, particularly on .css files. If there are any, that means it can't access the file.

[image: firefox network tab]

The permissions on a directory could be wrong, the webserver (nginx/apache) might not be able to access it, or you may have linked it incorrectly (is your website in a subfolder or at the root of the domain? do your links need leading slashes?).

Comment: I don't see any 404s. The index file is in the root directory and the template file is in a folder named "templates." The CSS do need slashes as they are in subfolders. Posting my code shortly. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The path to the CSS files are incorrect, set them correctly (Absolute or Relative)

```
<link href="file://///hqdaa0n02731-06/wtc$/css/bs_paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, min-device-width, resolution" />
<link href="file://///hqdaa0n02731-06/wtc$/js/plugins/css/bootstrap-accessibility_1.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="file://///hqdaa0n02731-06/wtc$/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link href="file://///hqdaa0n02731-06/wtc$/css/wtc_home_3box_pic_option.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="file://///hqdaa0n02731-06/wtc$/css/yamm_2014.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Should be like this:

**ABSOLUTE**

```
<link href="http://www.wtc.army.mil/css/yamm_2014.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**RELATIVE**

```
<link href="/css/yamm_2014.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis. I will fix this. Would it be a good idea to apply the Dreamweaver feature: Apply Template to Page either before or after I make the above changes in CSS?